# New component overwrite the previous one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Item from './components/item'
import './App.css'
class App extends Component {
    state = { item: "", array: [], check: false }
    setItem = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            item: event.target.value
        })
    }

    add = () => {
        let item = this.state.item;
        if (item != "") {
            let arr = []
            arr.push(item)
            this.setState({ item: "", array: arr, check: true })
        }
        console.log(this.state.array)
    }

    render() {
            return ( < div > < input type = "text"
                    value = { this.state.item }
                    onChange = { this.setItem }
                    / > < button onClick = { this.add } > Add < /button > {
                        this.state.check ? < div > {
                            this.state.array.map(item => < Item name = { item }
                                />) } < /div >: null
                            } < /div > );
                        }
                    }
                    export default App
```

I actually wrote this code for building a item buying remainder.The problem is first item added successfully but after that i can'nt add more item.Every time i tried it overwrite the previously added item.

Answer (score 1):

In your `add` function, if there is no item in the state, your are declaring `arr` to be a **new** (empty) array, and only pushing one item to it. Then, you use setState to overrwrite the current array with your new one (Which only contains one item)

To add to the array, you would need to first copy all of the items currently in it, then push onto them

```
add = () => {
  let item = this.state.item;
  if (item != '') {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      let arr = [...prevState.array]; // Shallow copy of the array currently stored in the state
      arr.push(item);
      return { item: '', array: arr, check: true };
    });
  }
  console.log(this.state.array);
};
```

Comment: Can you please explain your from this.setState.I am confused from that also explan about prevState.

Comment: It's using a function instead of an object to avoid asynchronous problems. [This is a good article](https://itnext.io/react-setstate-usage-and-gotchas-ac10b4e03d60) explaining about it

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your array every time you add a new item.
Try this inside the add function:

before

```
let arr = []
```

after

```
 let arr = this.state.array
```

Comment: This is bad practice. As doing `arr.push` would mutate the state directly

Comment: Didn't know that. Thanks for the advice